Serving static files in VIte React
I have a Vite React app and based on the domain, I want to serve assets statically of a particular folder.
I am going to use this same app for multiple partner and want to have different assets for different partner.
If the react app is being accessed from a.com then I want to serve all assets in src/partners/a and if the react app is being accessed from b.com then I want to serve all assets in src/partners/b.
Later I can use these assets in my code and have different assets for different domain.
How can i achieve that?
I tried using domain name and then conditionally render assets based on the domain name. But that approach was very messy.
